# How to stop pipeline filtering (Where-Object) on first match

Tags: powershell, break, pipeline

I searched but didn't find how to do it yet.
I am working on filtering data from large files (~2GB).
I used `Where-Object` and when it find match it continues to search for other matches which it makes sense.

Is it possible to stop it on the first match ?

For example **(#1)**:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")}
```

The output will be:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    666      38    26928      18672    92             568 svchost
    596      28    11516      16560    92             792 svchost
    425      14     5364       7036    45             832 svchost
    406      17     7032       8416    39            1004 svchost
```

**What I want** is to return the output after the first match:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    666      38    26928      18672    92             568 svchost
```

This is what I tried (also with Foreach-Object):

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {if($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){return $_}}
Get-Process | Where-Object {if($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){return $_;break;}}    
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {if($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){return $_}}
```

But it still returns the full output.
Reference:
[How to break Foreach loop in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911180/how-to-break-foreach-loop-in-powershell)
[Is it possible to terminate or stop a PowerShell pipeline from within a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278539/is-it-possible-to-terminate-or-stop-a-powershell-pipeline-from-within-a-filter)

**EDIT (explanation about the problem with large data):**
**Example (#2):**
I have two XMLs:
**A.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Events>
  <Event>
    <EventData Name="Time">09/10/2017 12:54:16</EventData>
    <EventData Name="WorkstationName">USER2-PC</EventData>
    <EventData Name="UserName">user2</EventData>
  </Event>  
</Events>
```

**B.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Events>
   <Event>
    <EventData Name="Time">09/10/2017 14:54:16</EventData>
    <EventData Name="WorkstationName">USER1-PC</EventData>
    <EventData Name="UserName">user1</EventData>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <EventData Name="Time">09/10/2017 13:54:16</EventData>
    <EventData Name="WorkstationName">USER2-PC</EventData>
    <EventData Name="UserName">user2</EventData>
  </Event> 
 ... (more 100,000 events like the above two)
</Events>
```

These XMLs are being loaded as objects:

```
$fileA = "C:\tmp\A.xml"
$a = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
$a.Load($fileA)

$fileB = "C:\tmp\B.xml"
$b = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
$b.Load($fileB)
```

Then I want to search for the first match of the same username:

```
$result = $b.Events.Event | Where-Object {
    (($_.EventData | where-object {$_.Name -eq "UserName"})."#text" -eq $username)
}

$result.EventData
```

In this case it waste of time to run over the rest of 99,999 events if I have match on the first event.

**EDIT (SOLVED):**
After reading Nick answer, there wasn't anything new I didn't try.
The command:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {if($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){ $_;break;}}
```

Indeed stops the `Where-Object` but it doesn't return the item.
This one can be solved by:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {if($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){ $someVar = $_;break;}}
```

Therefore I marked his answer.

Comment: `... | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -like 'svchost*' } | Select-Object -First 1`?

Comment: If you're filtering file data, why not use Select-String with the -List option to make it stop on the first match?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It will still pass over all the processes and after it will get the object with **all** the 'svchost.exe' processes it will select the first one. You can see that it pass all the objects by: `Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -like 'svchost*'; Write-Host $_} | Select-Object -First 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If **efficiency** is what you need you can try break it out in to a loop:

```
Get-Process | foreach {If ($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){$_;break}}
```

You can confirm it works with this check:

```
$i=0; Get-Process | foreach {$i++;$i; If ($_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")){$_;break}}
```

It will make the loop print out a number each time it loops, in my case it got to 115, Then if i do `(Get-Process).Count` I have `157` Processes, So it looped over my processes found the one we want and then stopped the loop.

As stated here in other answers, You can use `[0]`, On any array or list you can select a individual row using the index inside square brackets, Be careful though because attempting this on a null or empty object will throw a exception:

```
(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")})[0]
```

Or you can you `Select-Object` which works in a similar way but has more options than just Index and will not throw any error if the object is null or empty.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")} | Select-Object -First 1
```

How ever both of these options will still evaluate the entire list before you select the first result.

Comment: efficiency is what I need, it is important. Regarding the last two answer you mentioned, like you wrote, they still evaluate the entire list and therefore I am not interesting with them. Regarding your first suggestion, it is good and I also tried it when, but it doesn't return the request item. But I can hack this by saving the requested variable `{$someVar = $_;break}` and that way to solve it.

Comment: I'm seeing this work nicely as an independent command, but it doesn't work within a script - the script exits when it hits the `break`. Per https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html, it looks like piping into `foreach` treats it as an alias for `ForEach-Object`, which would explain why `break` acts like it would act outside a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Both, `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object` are Cmdlets. You cannot break Cmdlets (commands). What you can do instead is to use the keyword `foreach` like this

```
$process = Get-Process

foreach ($item in $process) {
    if ($item.Name -eq 'svchost') {
        $item
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you intend to use `break` rather than `return` here.

Comment: @vrdse The problem with this workaround that you still passing over all the object. More than that, you are doing it twice. First time to with: `$process = Get-Process` and second time with the loop: `foreach ($item in $process)`. In this case, the use of Where-Object is faster.

Comment: I think that highly depends on when the first item is found in the loop, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Super interesting. I don't know why, but this article contradicts our findings!

https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/save-time-with-select-object-first

I even tested it. Since PS3, `select-object -first` stops the pipeline

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree this answer is not well written but actually I believe it is the correct answer to the question, as adding this to the pipeline will actually stop its execution, much more elegantly than the other answers. I.e.: `Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName.StartsWith("svchost")} | Select-Object -First 1`. Not to mention it gives you full control over how many results you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering data from large files use a `StreamReader` instead of regular PowerShell cmdlets:

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'
$word     = 'something'

$rdr = [IO.File]::OpenText($filename)
while ($rdr.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $line = $rdr.ReadLine()
    if ($line -like "*${word}*") { break }
}
$rdr.Close()
$rdr.Dispose()
```

Comment: I edited my question, I put examples for the large data I am working on.  In this kind of data I am loading the data as XML objects so I don't see how to use the `StreamReader` in this case. The best thing I though is to use the pipe `Where-Object` but I can't stop it on the first match

Comment: I can use `foreach($event in $b.Events.Event){...}` but I thought that maybe using `Foreach-Object` in pipe line will be faster.